# SignalR OnReconnect new page browsed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

I recently learned about SignalR and implemented a Persistent Online Connection check where the repository of the states is a SQL database.
It correctly detects when a user is Online/Offline. The problem becomes when the user is Online browsing the `Home/Index.cshtml` and then goes to `Home/Edit.cshtml`, `OnDisconnected` gets fired thus it creates a new connection. If I will like to keep the connection open how to? I had placed the hub connection in the `_Layout.cshtml` but obviously this gets reloaded as a new page is browsed.
I attempted to increase:

```
GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(110);

GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45);

GlobalHost.Configuration.KeepAlive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
```

In the `Startup.cs` right before `app.MapSignalR();`. Did not work, not sure why.

Thus if I will like to keep a chat api the user will appear offline/online momentarily. I will like to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement `OnReconnected()` method, and keep your user online.

```
public override Task OnReconnected()
{
   string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;

   if (!_connections.GetConnections(name).Contains(Context.ConnectionId))
   {
       _connections.Add(name, Context.ConnectionId);
   }

   return base.OnReconnected();
}
```

Complete example [here](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections).

Answer (score 0):

In that case - create a master page (layout page in case of mvc) and in the master page, connect the user to the signalr server. So if the user will redirect to some other page, it will stll be connected with the signalr server.